# Filter data as per fiscal months in SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net

My stored procedure is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[chart_OutPatientDetailsOPD_monthwise]
    @year varchar(5)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        p.MName, SUM(p.New) New, SUM(p.Renew) Renew 
    FROM
        (SELECT 
             MONTH(DateTime) monthcn,
             SUBSTRING(DATENAME(MONTH, datetime), 0, 4) + '-' + 
                       DATENAME(YEAR, datetime) MName,
             0 New, 0 Renew 
         FROM
             PatientRenew 
         WHERE
             YEAR(datetime) BETWEEN @year and @year+1
         GROUP BY 
             DATENAME(YEAR, datetime),
             MONTH(DateTime), DATENAME(MONTH, datetime)

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 
            t.monthcn, t.MName, 0 New, SUM(t.NoofPatient) Renew 
        FROM
            (SELECT
                 MONTH(DateTime) monthcn,
                 SUBSTRING(DATENAME(MONTH, datetime), 0, 4) + '-' + 
                     DATENAME(YEAR, prn.datetime) MName,
                 COUNT(prn.MRNO) NoofPatient 
             FROM
                 PatientRenew prn
             WHERE
                 YEAR(PRN.datetime) BETWEEN @year AND @year + 1 
             GROUP BY 
                 DATENAME(YEAR, prn.datetime),
                 DATENAME(MONTH, prn.datetime),
                 MONTH(DateTime), prn.MRNO) t 
        WHERE
            t.NoofPatient > 1 
        GROUP BY
            t.MName, t.monthcn

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 
            t.monthcn, t.MName,
            SUM(t.NoofPatient) New, 0 Renew 
        FROM
            (SELECT
                 MONTH(DateTime) monthcn, 
                 SUBSTRING(DATENAME(MONTH, datetime), 0, 4) + '-' + 
                     DATENAME(YEAR, prn.datetime) MName,
                 COUNT(prn.MRNO) NoofPatient 
             FROM
                 PatientRenew prn
             WHERE
                   YEAR(PRN.datetime) BETWEEN @year AND @year + 1
             GROUP BY 
                 DATENAME(YEAR, prn.datetime),
                 DATENAME(MONTH, prn.datetime),
                 MONTH(DateTime), prn.MRNO) t 
         WHERE
             t.NoofPatient = 1 
         GROUP BY 
             t.MName, t.monthcn) p 
    GROUP BY 
        p.MName, p.monthcn 
    ORDER BY
        CHARINDEX(LEFT(p.MName, 3), 'AprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDecJanFebMar') 
END
```

and when I execute it like this:

```
EXEC chart_OutPatientDetailsOPD_monthwise '2016'
```

I get this result table :

```
mname       new  renew Apr-2017 566 467 Apr-2016    392 247 May-2017    671 521 May-2016    396 233 Jun-2016    380 297 Jun-2017    571 488
Jul-2016    440 244 Jul-2017    679 543 Aug-2017    612 435 Aug-2016    451 333
Sep-2017    628 504 Sep-2016    452 283 Oct-2017    467 271 Oct-2016    399 319
Nov-2016    368 308 Dec-2016    491 319 Jan-2017    486 411 Jan-2016    3   0
Feb-2017    645 533 Feb-2016    13  6 Mar-2016  117 16 Mar-2017 599 506
```

but I want data from April 2016 to March 2017

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Comment: Why is `@year`  a datatype of `varchar(5)`. Change it to an `INT`.

Answer (score 0):

Add filtering in where clause for all selects, it should select these dates. Can u amend existing procedure ?

```
Where convert ( varchar(10),prn.datetime,120) between '2016-04-01' and '2017-03-30'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update your SP to this :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[chart_OutPatientDetailsOPD_monthwise]
    @StartDate smalldatetime,
    @EndDate smalldatetime
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        p.MName, SUM(p.New) New, SUM(p.Renew) Renew 
    FROM
        (SELECT 
             MONTH(DateTime) monthcn,
             SUBSTRING(DATENAME(MONTH, datetime), 0, 4) + '-' + 
                       DATENAME(YEAR, datetime) MName,
             0 New, 0 Renew 
         FROM
             PatientRenew 
         WHERE
             PRN.datetime BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
         GROUP BY 
             DATENAME(YEAR, datetime),
             MONTH(DateTime), DATENAME(MONTH, datetime)

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 
            t.monthcn, t.MName, 0 New, SUM(t.NoofPatient) Renew 
        FROM
            (SELECT
                 MONTH(DateTime) monthcn,
                 SUBSTRING(DATENAME(MONTH, datetime), 0, 4) + '-' + 
                     DATENAME(YEAR, prn.datetime) MName,
                 COUNT(prn.MRNO) NoofPatient 
             FROM
                 PatientRenew prn
             WHERE
                 PRN.datetime BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
             GROUP BY 
                 DATENAME(YEAR, prn.datetime),
                 DATENAME(MONTH, prn.datetime),
                 MONTH(DateTime), prn.MRNO) t 
        WHERE
            t.NoofPatient > 1 
        GROUP BY
            t.MName, t.monthcn

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 
            t.monthcn, t.MName,
            SUM(t.NoofPatient) New, 0 Renew 
        FROM
            (SELECT
                 MONTH(DateTime) monthcn, 
                 SUBSTRING(DATENAME(MONTH, datetime), 0, 4) + '-' + 
                     DATENAME(YEAR, prn.datetime) MName,
                 COUNT(prn.MRNO) NoofPatient 
             FROM
                 PatientRenew prn
             WHERE
                   PRN.datetime BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
             GROUP BY 
                 DATENAME(YEAR, prn.datetime),
                 DATENAME(MONTH, prn.datetime),
                 MONTH(DateTime), prn.MRNO) t 
         WHERE
             t.NoofPatient = 1 
         GROUP BY 
             t.MName, t.monthcn) p 
    GROUP BY 
        p.MName, p.monthcn 
    ORDER BY
        CHARINDEX(LEFT(p.MName, 3), 'AprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDecJanFebMar') 
END
```

Please notice, i have changed the parameter to accept `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` and modify your `WHERE` clause like this `PRN.datetime BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate`
So now you can execute your SP like this :

```
EXEC chart_OutPatientDetailsOPD_monthwise '04-01-2016', '03-30-2017'
```